# Why does my AWS AppFlow setup not show any subobject for selection?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, amazon-appflow

I have just been given admin access to a Google Analytics portal that tracks the corporate website's activity. The tracked data are to be moved to Amazon S3 via AppFlow.

I followed official AWS documentation in how to setup the connection between GA and AWS. We have created the connection successfully but I came across an issue I can't find an answer to:

[image: No subobject available for choosing]

Subobject field is empty. Currently, there are already ~4 months worth of data so I was thinking it's not an empty data thing. This issue does not allow me to proceed creating the flow as it is a required field. Any thoughts?

note: *the client and the team is new to AWS, so we are setting it up as we go, learning on the way. thank you for the help!*

Comment: Have you tried by creating a upsolver account as explained in this blog https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/easily-ingest-and-analyze-google-analytics-data-with-upsolver-and-amazon-appflow/ ?

Comment: Hi Prabhakar! I will give this a shot. However is this step necessary for all AppFlow solutions? I was hoping a fix exists where Google Analytics can be integrated natively via just AppFlow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer! The Google analytics account should have a Universal Analytics property available. Here are a few links:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appflow/latest/userguide/google-analytics.html
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6370521?hl=en

Comment: Universal Analytics properties will stop collecting data starting July 1, 2023. So the solution here might not work after July 1, 2023.